# Unable to create Event Subscription for a topic

Tags: azure, subscription, azure-eventgrid, azure-rest-api

I am trying to create event subscription using rest api refering the above link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/version2019-06-01/eventsubscriptions/createorupdate#eventsubscriptionprovisioningstate

It does show me "provisioningState" as "Creating", and for a while I can also see on portal when it is creating but after few minutes it shows.

Write Subscription - Failed on portal and the subscription vanishes. and can see below logs

```
 "properties": {
        "statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"Internal error\",\"message\":\"The operation failed due to an internal server error. The initial state of the impacted resources (if any) are restored. Please try again in few minutes. If error still persists, report XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:5/17/2020 11:51:09 AM (UTC) to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket .\"}]}}"
    }
```

But I am able to create from portal. There is only issue with API.

Comment: - could you show the payload?

Comment: Is that you want to create an event grid subscription for your custom topic?

Comment: I'm having the same issue when trying to create a event subscription for system topic. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @HariprabuJagadeesan yes, it actually creates event subscription "one per region". So as the event Subscription with that particular name is already created, that was the reason I was not able to create.